# I'm having issue submitting an app for Android Auto

Tags: android, google-play-console, publishing, android-auto

I followed the official docs to create the Android Auto app, but I'm getting rejected with this message:

> At this time, we are only accepting apps within the Media, short form
> Messaging, or categories supported by the Android for Cars App
> Library. Media apps that use TSS engine readout for content are not
> permitted at this time.

It happens on the internal track, which shouldn't be reviewed at all, so I'm confused even more.

"Categories supported by the Android for Cars App Library" are, as I read:

- androidx.car.app.category.NAVIGATION
- androidx.car.app.category.PARKING
- androidx.car.app.category.CHARGING

This is what I added in the manifest

```
<service
    android:name=".service.CarService"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_logo">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.car.action.CAR_APP"/>
        <category android:name="androidx.car.app.category.NAVIGATION"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.application"
    android:resource="@xml/automotive_app_desc"/>
```

automotive_app_desc.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<automotiveApp>
    <uses name="template" />
</automotiveApp>
```

Frankly, I tried different variations and tried submitting anything that resulted in my app actually working in my testing using the desktop head unit.

Any help with this is appreciated, I will try anything :)

Answer (score 0):

I will share that I am going through something very similar.  I have submitted 28 releases with a full instruction and disclosure video, and privacy disclosure web page, including proper permissions requests and explanations.  After all this, about a 4 week period, I finally received a one time provisional pass for just one build.  They tell me now, the below.  This is very challenging, because my app uses a geofence to help you open/close your smart garage door as you get close to home, or are leaving.  It literally exists to make driving safer by minimizing distractions.

Should I try to submit the application as a messaging app?  Google seems to claim that won't be accepted per the above limited items of 3 choices, but they provide a slew of documentation about Messaging.

I will try that next, assuming I can find the proper permissions request and classification and I'll report back.

I chose "androidx.car.app.category.PARKING" because what else?  I could try messaging/notifications as the auto component only needs to do exactly that.

> Status: Provisional Pass Your app is accepted into the Android Auto
> program on Google Play with a Provisional Pass. During review, we
> noticed some issues that would usually fail for a production state
> app.
>
> Parking and Charging Functionality
>
> The parking or charging functionality in your app didn’t work as
> expected. Refer to the Android app quality for cars guidelines for
> more details.
>
> For example:
>
> The app didn’t provide meaningful functionality in its category
> relevant to driving.

This sheds a little light on Google's plans.  Supposedly, Google is eventually going to open up media and messaging.

https://www.engadget.com/google-android-for-cars-app-development-auto-automotive-211528472.html

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30360829)

Comment: @80sTron, did you manage to submit your app successfully to Android Auto? I'm having the same exact struggle with Google :(

Comment: It has been a significant battle. At this point, I only have my app accessible to a private list of beta testers, as Google has very vague terms in regards to it not meeting 'standards for being a navigation or parking app'.  I have had the best success using the parking framework, as I am not custom drawing a map.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue with our Android Auto app. I see Google's [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELeNmFrm4vM&t=884s) video: "Bringing your apps to cars" (released on 27 October 2021) says you can suggest new categories with this Google forms [URL](https://forms.gle/jeqE7qvPJr7gBKQL9). I'm hoping that if enough people ask, more categories will be added.

Comment: Update: We've submitted multiple times at this point, it gets approved sometimes and rejected other times. It is starting to look like it depends on who you get to review your app on the day. The rejection email always has the same generic rejection message ("App category not permitted"). Although they've added "For example, the app uses a permission that is not allowed for this app category" now, so it might now be a permissions issue. Unfortunately appealing the rejection just gives you the same message as the rejection email. So far, our Apple CarPlay app is looking a lot more promising.

Comment: For me, using the PARKING category instead of POI category seems to solve my problem. At least for now.