# Why was my Android automotive app category not approved?

Tags: android, android-manifest, automotive

I have been trying to publish an Android automotive application to Google Play Store, but it was rejected. The reason for the rejection was "App category not permitted. At this time, we are only accepting apps within categories supported by the Android for Cars App Library as well as the Media and Video categories."

The categories referenced above are Media apps (audio), Messaging apps, Navigation apps, Point of Interest (POI) apps and Video apps (https://developer.android.com/training/cars#supported-app-categories).

In our AndroidManifest.xml file, the category is defined like this :

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="androidx.car.app.category.POI" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="distractionOptimized" android:value="true" />
</activity>
```

So my question is, why does it say it was rejected due to "..only accepting apps within categories supported by the Android for Cars App Library as well as the Media and Video categories", when the category for the application is one of these categories?

I tried to appeal, but it says it can take up to 7 days, and it would be great knowing why as soon as possible.

I have tried to search for an answer, but I have not found anything in particular.
The only thing I noticed, was that other people put their category inside , like this:

```
<service
        android:name=".MyCarAppService"
        android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="androidx.car.app.CarAppService"/>
        <category android:name="androidx.car.app.category.POI"/>
      </intent-filter>
</service>
```

However, I have found that this is not always the case. An example in the documentation which does not use the (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/car/app/activity/CarAppActivity), says:

"The class representing a car app activity in the main display. This class is responsible for binding to the host and rendering the content given by its androidx.car.app.CarAppService."
And in the example provided, the code looks like this:

```
<activity
  android:name="androidx.car.app.activity.CarAppActivity"
  android:exported="true"
  android:launchMode="singleTask"
  android:label="@string/your_app_label">

  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data android:name="distractionOptimized" android:value="true"/>
</activity>
```

So my question remains; why does my app get rejected due to "not having a supported category", when the category is set to one of the five supported categories?

Comment: Like it said in the post, I did appeal to Google. But since answers to appeals can take up to seven days and it's time sensitive I asked here :)

Comment: FYI: our app is a toll passings calculator where you can plot in departure and destination to calculate the total costs from the toll passings.

Answer (score 1):

Final answer:

Check your androidx.car.app library version to determine which [category](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps#supported-app-categories) to use if you're building a Point-Of-Interest app:

- **Lower than 1.3**: Use PARKING or CHARGING categories.
- **1.3 and up**: Use POI category

We ended up using the new IOT category as that suited our app best, it worked with version 1.2 of the CarApp library, it passed the review for open testing (1.3 wasn't available yet on Xamarin at the time of writing this update).

*** Original post: ***

Unfortunately, this seems to be a common problem a lot of people are having that are trying to publish Android Auto apps. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68335935/im-having-issue-submitting-an-app-for-android-auto) Stack Overflow thread.

I'm also using the "androidx.car.app.category.POI" category since my app definitely does not fall under any of the other categories. Out of the 7 submissions I've done, only 3 have been approved so far, it seems the approvals are very sporadic. The rejection always has the same generic rejection message ("App category not permitted"). When you appeal the rejection, they just respond with the same rejection message.

New categories can be requested for Android Auto using this [URL](https://forms.gle/jeqE7qvPJr7gBKQL9).

Edit:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73891657/is-poi-category-valid-for-android-auto-submision-to-google-play?rq=1) Stack Overflow thread suggested using the PARKING category instead of POI. Which is interesting because according to Google's Android for cars [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps#supported-app-categories), the PARKING and CHARGING categories have been deprecated and should use POI instead now. I tried it and my build got approved.

Comment: We tried submitting the application again two days ago, after waiting 14 days without getting an answer to the appeal. We realised, after some time, that we were using androidx.car.app:1.1.0, which only approved three categories (parking, navigation and charging) while POI was included in androidx.car.app:1.3.0-beta01. As you said, parking and charging were deprecated in the latter version. Which version are you using?

Comment: We're using Xamarin to build our app. I used the latest package available for Xamarin, but I see now that it's also mapping the androidx.car.app:1.1.0 library. Which makes sense why we needed to use PARKING category instead. I've done two additional submissions since changing to PARKING and both got approved. I think what threw me off initially was that some builds got approved that used POI category. Very odd. I'll update the answer to mention the package versions for anyone looking at this post in the future.

Comment: Google actually gave an answer to our appeal now, which of course left us even more confused.  The only things they said were "Media apps that use TSS engine readout for content are not permitted at this time" and "For example, the app uses a permission that is not allowed for this app category. See Build a navigation app for more details". Which is very confusing, since it is neither a navigation app nor a media app. They also said "meet the requirements for Android Auto." which is weird since it is an automotive app (which is specified) and not an Android Auto app.

Comment: Yes, we got the same generic response for our rejection and our rejection appeal: 
"• App category not permitted. At this time, we are only accepting apps within the Media, short form Messaging, or categories supported by the Android for Cars App Library. Media apps that use TSS engine readout for content are not permitted at this time.
o For example, the app uses a permission that is not allowed for this app category. See Build a navigation app for more details."
Unfortunately, the response isn't really helpful. Did it not work for you to change your category to PARKING or CHARGING?

Comment: We are using `androidx.car.app.category.NAVIGATION` which is supported in version 1.1.0, 1.2.0 and 1.3.0-beta01. However we have been also rejected with the same reasons.
Resubmitting only gets another automatic reply and appealing doesn't help either, since the reviewer is just linking the Google guidelines that we already followed step by step.

It looks like the AAOS / Android Auto dev ecosystem is totally broken in Android at the moment.

Comment: We will try to submit the app again today with category changed to PARKING instead of POI to see what happens. Will update you if anything happens :)

Comment: The app once more got rejected with the same feedback ("At this time, we are only accepting apps within categories supported by the Android for Cars App Library as well as the Media and Video categories.") when we tried to change cateogry to PARKING. I have no idea what we should do next.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that you still have not been able to get approval for your app. Android Auto's review process and feedback is just terrible. The only other thing I can think of is to make sure that you request all permissions from AA / AAOS before using that functionality. Our app asks the user all permissions when they open the app on their phone already so I didn't think of the scenario where the user opens the app first on AA before launching the app on their phone the first time, which would cause the app to crash because the permissions weren't requested first.

Comment: I'm also not sure if Google approves hello world test apps, it might need to be a fully-fledged app to get approval. But honestly, I'm just speculating from our app's rejections and approvals. It is a guessing game at this point. I'm just hoping they don't suddenly start rejecting our app again in the future.

Comment: This issue on Google's tracker shows the level of frustration we are all experimenting. I wonder if we should all post there to get Google's attention on the topic (not sure if it would help though):
https://issuetracker.google.com/u/2/issues/213935722

Comment: Not a bad idea. We filed an issue as well here https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/260596923

Comment: I have upvoted both your issues, hopefully something can be done about this.

Comment: @CVStrydom, in the issue we have provided our android.manifest file. It has come to our attention that we have not included CarAppService  in a <Service> tag, which many other examples we have seen does. Do you think that can be the issue? Today we received answer to another appeal, but it was the same generic answer as earlier, so we are once again left in the dark.

Comment: Yes, it needs to be in a <service> tag. Android Auto runs as a background service on Android and is not an activity. See [this document](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps#declare-carappservice) on how to declare your CarAppService.

Comment: I see Google has now added an [IOT category](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps/iot) to Android Auto, that also uses the Cars App Library, which use case fits our app perfectly. My suspicion is that it will only be available from version 1.3 and onward. So, I'll wait for it to be in the stable release state before switching over.

Comment: Google rejected our app again when we moved to open testing, so I targeted version 1.2 of the CarApp library (as it is the latest that is currently supported by Xamarin) and used the IOT category and it passed the review for open testing.